# Angular - Create HTML Elements and Angular Components dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web, dynamically-generated

I am currently working on an Angular 10 project where I have to add native HTML-elements like div, table, p, h1 to the DOM (this could be achieved in Angular with the DomSanitizer) from the TypeScript class. But I also want to create an Angular component inside an created div.

Because creating just one component is easy with the ComponentFactoryResolver.

For example, this should be created from Typescript dynamically:

```
<div>
<my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?
Kind regards,
Steve

Answer (score -1):

I think is this what you're looking for:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'example',
      templateUrl: '<my-component></my-component>',
      styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
    })
    export class ExampleComponent {
    }
```

You don't need `<div>` unless you use him for style or other thing.